# How to divide window.innerWidth by div.style.width in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, font-size

I'm trying to create divs along the screen. I want the number of divs to be equal to the screen's width (1920px) / 1em (font size width). I'm having difficulty and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
function main(){
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.width = '1em';
  div.style.height = '1em';
  div.style.background = 'red';
  i = 0;
  while(i < (window.innerWidth / div.style.width)){
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    i++;
  }
}
main();
```

Comment: `appendChild(div)` won't make copies of `div`. It will append the same element over and over and an element can't be in 2 places at the same time. End result of the loop is same as appending that element once with no loop

Comment: Would giving the first div an ID of i then appending to that div work?

Comment: You need to create a new one each time you append

Comment: How do I make it new?

Comment: create the elements inside the loop. But also have to check your math. can't divide by `"1em"`

Comment: How do I divide by 1em then or convert it into an int?

Comment: `1em = 16px` by default, unless you changed it.

Comment: Okay now how do I create a new one each time instead of the same one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below code to create the div according to screen width. You have to convert the `1em` value to `px` by using

**var em = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).fontSize);**

```js
function main() {
  var em = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).fontSize);
  console.log(window.innerWidth, em, (window.innerWidth / em))
  for (i = 0; i < (window.innerWidth / em); i++) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.width = '1em';
    div.style.height = '1em';
    div.style.background = 'red';
    document.body.appendChild(div);
  }
}
window.onload = function() {
  main();
};
```

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
```

```html
<body id="body"></body>
```